# Make smaller clickable area within div container?

Tags: css, overflow

What I'm trying to do is fairly complex.

The basic idea is that I have a wrapper div, say 20 x 20 px, that is hidden and fades in once I hover the mouse over it and fades back out when the mouse is removed. I have this part figured out.

My next step was to include a div containing an image inside the wrapper div. The image div which is bigger (about 300 x 400px), overflows the boundaries of the wrapper div so that the entire image is visible and, as a child of the wrapper div, also fades in upon hover.

This brings me to my issue(s):

**1.** When I hover over the area, the image fades in like I want it to, but the top right corner is bound by the wrapper border, and it overflows to the bottom left only.

**2.** When I hover over any area the image covers and not just the wrapper area, the image will appear.

**desired result for issue 1:** I want to position the image div within the wrapper so that it overflows up and left, as well as down and right. In other words when I hover over the wrapper area, I want the image to fade in completely eclipsing the wrapper area so that the wrapper area is basically centered within the image area

**Desired result for issue 2:** I ONLY want the fade in effect to be activated when I hover over the 20 x 20 wrapper area. When I hover over any area the 300 x 400 image WOULD cover when visible I don't want anything to happen. On mouse off It wouldn't matter to me if I had to leave the area of the image or the area of the wrapper for the fade out to begin, but if it's possible to limit all hover activation/deactivation to the 20 x 20 area only, that would be cool.

I could so easily use the old image1 over image2; on hover, image 1 fades out to reveal image 2 trick, but it's all hell since I want the fade activation location to be within the area being faded itself.

Isk

---

**UPDATE:**

I have figured out issue number 1.

so now I just need to figure out my second problem and I'll be all set.

To get a visual of my progress so far, here's my website: http://silentnoizemusic.com

Scroll down to the area with the billboard that reads "SALES@silentnoizemusic.com" and hover the mouse over the black twitter icon to the upper left of the billboard.

Just as a reminder, I want the fade in action to take place ONLY when I hover the mouse over the twitter Icon area and not when I hover over the area the fading image covers. The image is placed within a smaller div wrapper set to visible overflow. So if you were to set the overflow to hidden you'd see that there is a square area with a yellow border that fades in when you hover over the twitter Icon. When I set the wrapper back to overflow: visible;, I only want that square area to activate the hover function and not any of the area around the square that the invisible overflowing content occupies.

It would be preferable if there was non-javascript solution due to coding restrictions, but if js is the only option then I'll give it a try anyway.

Thanks again,

Isk

Comment: I see you are using jquery already... this will be so easy with javascript... Interested in that code?

Comment: Though I should probably let you know that a lot of that code on the page is preset. I'm technically not even supposed to be adding additional script, as that is one of the restrictions of page design on the service I'm using, so I'm not sure if inserting a javascript code would work in this case. That's why I've been so focused on trying to figure this out using only CSS and HTML thus far, as those are allowed.

Comment: Ok I figured out my first problem with a little more tweaking, so now I'm just left with my second problem. I've updated my initial post with the details.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurring because your image is a child of the wrapper div and hovering over it is considered as hovering over the wrapper div.
If you are not terribly against a Javascript solution, here's my suggestion:
Take the bigger image **outside** the small wrapper div, i.e. it's no longer a child. But position the wrapper and this image in the same places as before. Then, on an onmouseover event on the smaller div, change the visibility of the image as before. On an onmouseout event, hide the bigger image again.
In order to change the properties of an element in response to actions on some other element you would need Javascript and CSS won't do.

This is the HTML and JS. Put the whole thing in your HTML file:

```
<script>
function show(div-id)
{
document.getElementById(div-id).style.visibility="visible";
}
function hide(div-id)
{
document.getElementById(div-id).style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>

<div id="small-button" onmouseover="show('bigger-image')" onmouseout="hide('bigger-image')">...</div>
<div id="bigger-image" style="visibility:hidden">...</div>
```

Comment: Damn, I was hoping it wouldn't come to that, because I'm pretty sure that javascript coding won't work in my specific case. I'll give it a shot though as it seems like it makes sense. Would you mind providing me with an example code of how I would perform the function, if you know? I'm not so good with js coding as of now.